# 'LoginPage' object has no attribute 'run_main_options'

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I followed a tutorial from sentdex to get a functional tkinter GUI that can navigate between different frames, while that was successful I implemented this to my main python bank system but I seem to be getting an attribute error.

This is the code for the tkinter with multiple frames:

```
class BankSystemGUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (LoginPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame(LoginPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

```
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label_1 = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to the Python Bank System", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        label_2 = tk.Label(self, text="~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label_2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Admin login", command=lambda: self.run_main_options)
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit Python Bank System", command=lambda: self.run_main_options)
        button2.pack()
```

And this is my code to run the main admin options, I used a button so when it's clicked it would display this menu in the terminal:

```
def run_main_options(self):
    loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        choice = self.main_menu()
        if choice == 1:
            username = input("\n Please input admin username: ")
            password = input("\n Please input admin password: ")
            msg, admin_obj = self.admin_login(username, password)
            print(msg)
            if admin_obj != None:
                self.run_admin_options(admin_obj)
             elif choice == 2:
                print("This option is not available yet")

            elif choice == 3:
                loop = 0
        print("\n Thank-You for stopping by the bank!")
```

I'm somehow getting a **`'LoginPage' object has no attribute 'run_main_options'`** error so what do I need to add or change in any of this code to get it working?

Comment: As it stands `def run_main_options(...` is not a `methode` of `class LoginPage`. Check your Indentations!

Comment: Is there anyway I can get the class Login to run the function run_main_options from another class? The run_main_options is in the BankSystem class.

Comment: Done, thank you for your help!